# How to set pdf options using Export command

Tags: export, pdf-format

I found that there is an options using right click "save graphic as pdf", like this
[image]
[image]

I test "using most compatible vector representation", and result is good.

But how to set these options in `Export`? If I use `Export` directly like

```
Export['test.pdf',DensityPlot[Sin[x y],{x,1,10},{y,1,10},PlotPoints->30,MaxRecursion->3]]
```

The result pdf is 67MB !!! And it looks quite bad in my pdf xchange editor. Like this

[image]

However, if save it using "using most compatible vector representation" option, the pdf is only 3.9MB, and quality is quite good and it is vector image. like this

[image]